# label line with help of plotchar

Tags: pine-script

guys i need help to add labels in my script with the help of" plotchar ", yesterday's high and low lines with text H and L ,i have tried myself but getting multiple labels on the chart as shows in this [picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzzmt.jpg) , i tried using show_last but it will show label on only on last bar and its kinda messy on live chart [picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhA86.jpg) , i want this text to be displayed on left side of the line , like in this picture [picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVbGg.jpg) this label is done with using " plotchar ", unfortunately that's a protected script, anyone knows the solution for this how to replicate the same result as shown in picture 3 , here's my script

```
//@version=4
study("daily high low ?", overlay=true)

hl = input(true, title="Show Previous Day Highs & Lows", group="KETAN ULTIMATE COMBO")

dhigh = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", high[1], lookahead=true)
dlow = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", low[1], lookahead=true)
plot(timeframe.isintraday and hl ? dhigh : na, title="Daily High", style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.rgb(255,0,0), linewidth=2)
plot(timeframe.isintraday and hl ? dlow : na, title="Daily Low", style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.rgb(0,128,0), linewidth=2)

plotchar(timeframe.isintraday and hl ? dhigh : na, title="high", location=location.absolute,color=color.blue, char = "", text ="H")
plotchar(bar_index ? dlow : na , title="low", location=location.absolute, color=color.blue, char = "", text ="L")
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't review all of your code, but you can detect that a day has changed with `change(dayofmonth)`

```
//@version=4
study("daily high low ?", overlay=true)

hl = input(true, title="Show Previous Day Highs & Lows", group="KETAN ULTIMATE COMBO")

dhigh = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", high[1], lookahead=true)
dlow = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", low[1], lookahead=true)
plot(timeframe.isintraday and hl ? dhigh : na, title="Daily High", style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.rgb(255,0,0), linewidth=2)
plot(timeframe.isintraday and hl ? dlow : na, title="Daily Low", style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.rgb(0,128,0), linewidth=2)

plotchar(change(dayofmonth) ? dhigh : na, title="high", location=location.absolute,color=color.blue, char = "", text ="H")
plotchar(change(dayofmonth) ? dlow : na , title="low", location=location.absolute, color=color.blue, char = "", text ="L")
```

Comment: thank you so much brother this is exactly what i'm looking for